# "Simulate Location" seems to get stuck

Tags: ios, xcode

I am on the latest version of XCode and using iOS 8. I have a scheme with a default location set and it seems to get stuck in the simulated location even on a device. I have tried, setting the location to "None" and unchecking the simulate box, and still on an iPhone 5 it keeps using New York, NY as the simulated location. Curiously, this doesn't happen on the iPhone 6. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the device seemed to clear this problem.